# objective-c: play video by removing the default fullscreen, etc functionality

Tags: ios, objective-c, video

I am building an iPhone app which will play video onClick from youtube. I am using UIWebView for this. But the issue is the video goes into fullscreen onClick. Plus I want to remove the default controls for fullscreen, done, play provided by iPhone.
Following is the screen shot I wish to change:
[image]

As seen in the image :
1) How do I remove the done button?
2) how do i disable the seek bar to make user- non interactable?
3) Remove the fullscreen button?

I have my own controls for fullscreen and volume functionality. I want to make the video to be controlled by my custom controls. But whenever the video starts playing, it goes into fullscreen mode as shown in the above pic.
[image]

As you can see in this screen below, I wish to use these custom controls.
Please give a solution for this. How do i solve it?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to customize the MPMovieControlStyle values provided by Apple. What you need to do is is turn off the Apple controls (MPMovieControlStyleNone) and then create your own custom controls. Apple is fine with you putting your own UIViews in to the hierarchy here, so you can get started with something like this:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: YOUR_URL];
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
UIView *movieView = moviePlayer.view;
[movieView addSubview: _movieControlsView];
[movieView bringSubviewToFront: _movieControlsView];
```

Where _movieControlsView was set up earlier in code or in IB.

Aesthetically, you can do what you want, but I would recommend sticking with something that looks like Apple's choices so as not to confuse the user.

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: But i am using UIWebView to load the youtube video

Comment: In Webview you can't use custom control for Player. it is not same as Native MpmovieplayerController.

Comment: i have to load youtube video hence i am using webview, for live streaming

Comment: yes that's right. you can not load youtube URL other than Webview. so i don't think in webview you can assign custom controls for movie player.