# ios: youtube video mute through custom button

Tags: ios, video, youtube, youtube-api

My application contains a video with custom UIButtons to manage the video.
By using the Youtube iFrame api I have managed to play the youtube video in UIWebView and hide all its default controls(for fullscreen, volume, etc.).
Now I want to control the video through custom buttons.
How do i do that?
- fullscreen UIButton: to make the video fullscreen
- Mute/Unmute button: to mute/unmute the video

refer the screen from my other question:

[objective-c: play video by removing the default fullscreen, etc functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803806/objective-c-play-video-by-removing-the-default-fullscreen-etc-functionality)

How do i solve this? Code for video in UIWebview:

```
 NSString *htmlString =@"<!DOCTYPE html><html> <body><div id=\"player\"></div><script>var tag = document.createElement('script');tag.src = \"https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api\";var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);var player;function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {player = new YT.Player('player', {height: '196',width: '309',videoId: 'GOiIxqcbzyM',playerVars: {playsinline: 1, controls: 0}, events: {'onReady': onPlayerReady,'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange}});}function onPlayerReady(event) {event.target.playVideo();}var done = false;function onPlayerStateChange(event) {if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);done = true;}}function stopVideo() {}</script></body></html>";
_webViewVideo.delegate = self;

static NSString *youTubeVideoHTML = @"<iframe webkit-playsinline width=\"309\" height=\"200\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/GOiIxqcbzyM?feature=player_detailpage&playsinline=1\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>";
[_webViewVideo loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
```

Comment: How did you hide the default controls and did you find a way to control the video through custom controls?

Answer (score 0):

This combination does the video to hide controls

```
NSDictionary *playerVars = @{
                             @"controls" : @0,
                             @"playsinline" : @1,
                             @"autohide" : @1,
                             @"showinfo" : @0,
                             @"modestbranding" : @1,
                             @"rel":@0
                             };
```

To make the video full screen on button click, try saving the current video elapsed time and by changing playerVars to show controls and trigger full screen button action programmatically(the video plays in full screen) and the seek to method to play the video from elapsed time.

For mute/unmute , try reducing the current phone volume programmatically to mute and set it on unmute

i dont think apple provides the api to change the volume.
only user can do it using the hardware controls